# Troubleshooting 404 WCF Service error

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I've recently upgraded an ASP.Net application from .Net framework 3.5 to 4.0.  The application includes a WCF Service and after the upgrade it's returning a 404 error.

The error message is below:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /ws/ProviderService.svc


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.42; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.42
```

The web.config has

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="Common/Pages/404b.htm"/>
```

and it should be redirecting 404's to a custom page.  If I try to access a non existent .asmx service then it correctly redirects to the 404b.htm page.

It looks like the .Net framework 4.0 isn't handling but is somehow being picked up by .Net framework 2.0.

The site is on IIS7 and Windows Server 2008.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Even it is .Net 4.0, I believe asp.net says Net framework 2.0, what is the setting for the customerror tag in web.config

Make sure it is set as "Off" not  "RemoteOnly"